# How to obtain the state matrix of this trajectory?

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Continuous-time LTI case.
I have a problem getting the state matrix of this trajectory.
[image: trajectory]

One element of the state matrix is known.
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} a & 4  \\c & d  \end{pmatrix}
$$

I know that one Eigenvalue is 0, $s_1 = 0$, and one Eigenvector is $p_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1  \end{pmatrix}$.
With the equation $s_1 - a*p_{11} + s - 4*p_{12} = 0$, i get $a = -4$.
I also found out that $c=-d$.
But I am stuck now. I don't know how to get the other elements.
Is there more information to get from the image?

Help appreciated...

### German version:

Für ein freies System  2. Ordnung der Form $\frac{dx}{dt} = A*x$ ist das dazugehörige Trajektorienbild gegeben.
Außerdem ist die zugehörige Systemmatrix  A (teilweise) bekannt:
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} a & 4  \\c & d  \end{pmatrix}
$$
Bestimmen Sie die fehlenden Elemente der Systemmatrix  A . 
(HINWEIS: Benützen Sie das angegebene Trajektorienbild!)

### Translation:

The trajectory image associated with a free system of second order of the form $\frac{dx}{dt} = A*x$ is given.
Further, the associated system matrix $A$ is (partially) known:
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} a & 4  \\c & d  \end{pmatrix}
$$
Determine the missing elements of the system matrix $A$.
(HINT: Use the given trajectory image!)

Comment: A Google search seems to indicate that "system matrix" and "trajectory image" are terms of art in optical imaging. Neither of them has a Wikipedia entry. I suspect you'll have a much better chance of getting an answer if you define these terms and explain what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I tried to explain it better. All my studies are in german so it it not that easy to translate the math specific expressions.

Comment: You can try writing in German, and then somebody else can translate for you here.

Comment: German version added. Topic is control engineering.

Comment: I added a translation to English. Are you sure it says "2. Ordnung"? The differential equation given is of first order.

Comment: @madmax Are those arrows going only horizontally? I really can't read what's actually going on on the plot.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to see for me also. These arrows are going only horizontally and are showing to the trajectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ruhezone` is the set of the equilibrium points, then $\dot x=0$ when $x_1(t)=x_2(t)$, and if those are arrows pointing towards the $x=y$ line, the elements of the eq. point set are stable. The question, as far as I understand, wants you to make a qualitative assesment of how this line is the attractor of the trajectories in its neighborhood.

From the first hint, $A_{12} = 4$ we obtain 
$$
\pmatrix{\dot x_1\\\dot x_2} = \pmatrix{-4 &4\\ c&d}\pmatrix{x_1\\  x_2}
$$
Just test for yourself, whenever $x_1>x_2$, $\dot x_1<0$ and $x_1<x_2$, $\dot x_1>0$.

Now, this is where I might mistaken: if those arrows are for vector field annotation and horizontal arrow means the vector field has no $x_2$ contribution, that means $\dot x_2$ is zero everywhere no matter what. Hence $c=d=0$.

$$
\pmatrix{\dot x_1\\\dot x_2} = \pmatrix{-4 &4\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{x_1\\  x_2}
$$

Indeed, `0` is an eigenvalue and $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1  \end{pmatrix}$ is the eigenvector together with `-4` and $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0  \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you, I think your answer sounds plausible. Those arrows are for vector field annotation.